# State and Federal tax will be paid by the company

Tags: recruitment, united-states, contracts, taxes

Recruiter said that my rate is too high and proposed low rate, but they pay my taxes:

> Rate of $xx/Hr on W2(State and Federal tax will be paid by the
>   company)

I asked does it mean that I get these money without any deductions. He said "yes".

It's W2 contract in US.

Can it be true?

How I can be sure that when I complete my taxes, it will not be required to pay all these taxes?

Comment: can you give us some numbers to help us understand what the recruiter means?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep, his supposed hourly rate = mine - $10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whatever they're offering, it doesn't do you any good (or harm). W-2 is for employees and shows your wages, salaries and tips, plus any amount withheld for state and federal income tax. The alternative is a 1099 which just shows how much you were paid as a contractor. You'll end up paying the same tax either way unless you have some unusual tax situation. **Either they're stupid or they think you are.** You can't take any deductions on a W-2. You report the income it shows and deduct elsewhere on your return with your customer or employer not knowing what you deduct.  The company doesn't pay your taxes: it withholds tax for you and sends to the IRS. Otherwise you would have to pay it yourself.

Comment: You won't pay the same tax either way.  If you're a 1099 contractor, you owe both the employer and employee portions of payroll taxes.  W2 employees owe only the employee portion.  That's one of the reasons that you need to make a higher hourly rate as a 1099 contractor in order to net the same amount in the end.

Comment: @Justin Cave: you're quite right. A contractor can also subtract commuting costs from income. I was focusing on income tax.